# Wired Connection not working with Parrot OS booted on Macbook Pro 2016

Tags: macos, debian, internet, ethernet, wired-networking

I dual booted my mac with Parrot OS. I have perfectly fine wireless connection but Ethernet is not recognized. When I installed the system, it said that the Ethernet card could not be identified and asked me to choose one from the list. I thought I could probably just fix it later so I said no network. Is there any way to install the correct driver onto Parrot (which is Debian based)?

## Outputs:

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

ifconfig

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 6540  bytes 416615 (406.8 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6540  bytes 416615 (406.8 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 26:7e:42:4c:53:52  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 31337  bytes 31058922 (29.6 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 23980  bytes 5218400 (4.9 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 96:ab:7b:be:6b:71  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Thanks

Comment: How is this security related?

Comment: No, it's configuration problem. Voted to migrate it.